# Load .scn file as SCNNode LOSS animations

Tags: ios, scenekit

When I load `Horse.scn` to a SCNNode, the animations are lost.

```
    func addHorse(for parentNode:SCNNode, postion:SCNVector3){
    guard let virtualObjectScene = SCNScene(named: "Horse.scn") else {
        return
    }

    let wrapperNode = SCNNode()

    for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        child.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        child.movabilityHint = .movable
        wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
    }
    wrapperNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.001,0.001,0.001)
    wrapperNode.position = postion;
    parentNode.addChildNode(wrapperNode)
}
```

If I load scene from `Horse.dae` file, everything is fine. Setting rootNode 's playing property to YES doesn't work.